# Java Convert PDF form Fields into Editable Form Fields

Tags: java, pdf

I have a PDF form which contains some fields.I want to make an application/utility in Java that takes a PDF file and convert its fields into editable fields, so that i can fill them using any PDF application(Adobe Reader/Foxit Reader) on Windows.Is there any library in java that can do this?

Comment: Do you mean by *"a PDF form which contains some fields"* a pdf which contains graphics humans would interpret as form fields but which are not actual AcroForm form fields? Adding such form field definitions should be possible with any general purpose pdf library. Obviously, though, you should not expect those libraries to automatically recognize those field-like graphics as fields out-of-the-box, you'll either have to obtain coordinates manually or implement some field-graphics recognition code.

Comment: Yeah you are absolutely right. I need to obtain the coordinates for that. Can you please give me some link or anything for this manually obtaining coordinates method?

Comment: It simply completely depends on the nature of your original PDF. If it's a scan, there is nothing PDF specific you can do before some image analysis software with form field detection features analyzed the scan. If it's a PDF with the fields drawn using PDF vector graphics, PDF libraries can help you. And what you can always do: print out the PDF and measure manually. Having retrieved coordinates either way, you now can use any general purpose pdf library to create the AcroForm definitions.